# Ordered string to array PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a problem with converting the string:

```
$str = "1. List of word synonyms 2) Glass plastic products 3. Other product";
```

into an array list:

```
Array(
  [0] => List of word synonyms
  [1] => Glass plastic products
  [2] => Other product
)
```

I tried using preg_replace, but I can't come up with a pattern that would be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_split()` to split the string into an array based on a regular expression pattern. In this case, you can split on any number followed by a period and a space. Here's an example code snippet:

```
$str = "1. List of word synonyms 2) Glass plastic products 3. Other product";
$array = preg_split('/\d+\.\s+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
```

And this will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => List of word synonyms
    [1] => Glass plastic products
    [2] => Other product
)
```